# Is it possible to generate dynamic objects x times

Tags: python

I would like to get a number from the user lets say 3.

Now i want to create objects with the name 'user1 = User() , user2 = User(), user3 = User()'

is that possible at all?

or is there an alternative?

Comment: Use dictionary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use a dict:

```
result = dict()
for i in range(10):
    result['user' + i] = 'some value'
```

Comment: You helped me a lot. I tried it with lists but couldn't get it to work Thanks!